# Getting error while running Selenium code on Ubuntu 18.04 for Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng, ubuntu-18.04

I have a cloud server having Ubuntu 18.04. I got an installed Desktop environment.  I installed all the necessary things - eclipse, TestNG etc

I am trying to open a website but on sever i am getting below error.  The code is working perfectly on my machine.  Pls note that I am not using any wrong path to drivers

Below is the COMPLETE CONSOLE LOGS

```
/root/Desktop/qa-frontend-automation-web/src/main/java/AllDrivers/chromedriver: 1: /root/Desktop/qa-frontend-automation-web/src/main/java/AllDrivers/chromedriver: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
/root/Desktop/qa-frontend-automation-web/src/main/java/AllDrivers/chromedriver: 1: /root/Desktop/qa-frontend-automation-web/src/main/java/AllDrivers/chromedriver: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
Jul 15, 2020 9:42:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-72-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: GiveWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at com.NewProjectName.FrontendAutomation.DesktopWeb.HelpFiles.GiveWebDriver.getDriver(GiveWebDriver.java:70)
    at com.NewProjectName.FrontendAutomation.DesktopWeb.HelpFiles.HandeOneSession.recieveCSV(HandeOneSession.java:40)
    at com.NewProjectName.FrontendAutomation.DesktopWeb.ExecutionStart.ExecuteAllCSV.testing(ExecuteAllCSV.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:77)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:15)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:3516/status] to be available after 20000 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Try another chrome driver and i suggest you to give the driver execute permission. Try "sudo chmod 777 path...".

Comment: Done that.. still not working.. same error

Comment: What is ")" ? 
Are you trying to pass driver name with ")"?

Comment: No, I am using exact same code on Mac, Windows - it is working..  There is no ) used